# TypeORM innerJoinAndSelect does not select

Tags: javascript, mysql, typeorm

I'm using the QueryBuilder from TypeORM and want to inner join a table that has no relation with the other table.

```
const stats = await createQueryBuilder(PlayerLevelStats, 'pls')
    .innerJoinAndSelect(
        PlayerClassLevelStats, "pcls",
        'pls.race = :race AND pls.class = :class AND pcls.class = :class AND pls.level = pcls.level',
        { race, class: plrClass, level },
    )
    .getMany();
```

It correctly returns the columns of `PlayerLevelStats`, but not from `PlayerClassLevelStats`. The query that is generated returns the correct data when I run it in Sequel Pro, but not in my code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should be using innerJoinAndMapOne or innerJoinAndMapMany to join on tables, which do not have defined relationships in entities.